# SessionStorage and json objects

Tags: javascript, json, session-storage

```
user: {firstName: "loki", lastName: "ch"}
```

I am storing this user in session storage.

```
$window.sessionStorage.user = user;
```

when i retrieved it back using
 `$window.sessionStorage.user`, i got:

```
[object Object]
```

I want in JSON.
Any suggestions?

Comment: No way to say without knowing what `user` contains. Looks like it's been already converted to a JSON string.

Comment: it's a hack but `user: JSON.parse(user)` would fix it. Go back to where `user` gets defined and fix it there though. Show all relevant code

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Convert it to JSON before saving it.

```
$window.sessionStorage.user = JSON.stringify(user);
```

Then when you're loading it, parse the JSON.

```
var user = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the item

```
sessionStorage.setItem('user', user)
```

Get the item

```
var item = sessionStorage.getItem('user')
var user = item ? JSON.stringify(item) : {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently for Typescript users in React for example, You'll have to pass it as a string

```
JSON.parse(`${sessionStorage.getItem("session storage item name")}`)
```