# i am not able to load array from session storage in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sessionstorage

I am not able to restore a created array in html and reuse it again.
I have used Json but do not work with me.
in the below code. I'm trying to reload items which is an array created in another page. when i try to load it, it did not work. how can i fix this?
does json need header file?
Thank you.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var count=sessionStorage.getItem('items');      
)};
```

Comment: have you set items in sessionStorage first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SessionStorage and json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817776/sessionstorage-and-json-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sessionStorage`property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin.It is two way process first of all `stringify`object before storing to session and second  `parse`to getting back .

```
     var user = {'name':'John'};
     sessionStorage['user'] = JSON.stringify(user);
     console.log(sessionStorage['user']);
     var obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage['user']);
     console.log(Object.keys(obj).length);
```

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).**Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated**.
[More About session storage.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your array to a string before setting and back again when your get the item

```
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
sessionStorage.setItem("letters", JSON.stringify(letters));
var storedLetters = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("letters"));

console.log(storedLetters);
```